# Hibernate and JDBC in one transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jdbc, transactions

I have a method, marked as @Transactional.
It consists of several functions, one of them uses JDBC and the second one - Hibernate, third - JDBC.
The problem is that changes, made by Hibernate function are not visible in the last functions, that works with JDBC.

```
@Transactional
void update() {
  jdbcUpdate1();
  hibernateupdate1();
  jdbcUpdate2(); // results of hibernateupdate1() are not visible here    
}
```

All functions are configured to use the same datasource:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
        <property name="targetDataSource" ref="targetDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="targetDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true" scope="singleton">
       <!-- settings here -->
    </bean>
```

myDataSource bean is used in the code. myDataSource.getConnection() is used to work with connections in jdbc functions and

```
getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
            public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
               ... 
            }
        });
```

is used in hibernate function.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

First, avoid using JDBC when using hibernate.

Then, if you really need it, use to [`Session.doWork(..)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork%28org.hibernate.jdbc.Work%29). If your hibernate version does not yet have this method, obtain the `Connection` from `session.connection()`.

Comment: For those, who will get here from Google, my solution for this problem. I added session.flush() at the end of hibernate flush function. After it, it's write result is available in next jdbc read function(in the same transaction).

Answer (score 2):

You can use JDBC and Hibernate in the same transaction if you use the right Spring setup:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myDao" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="MyDaoImpl">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This assumes that the JDBC portion of your DAO uses JdbcTemplate. If it doesn't you have a few options:

- Use DataSourceUtils.getConnection(javax.sql.DataSource) to get a connection
- Wrap the DataSource you pass to your DAO (but not necessarily the one you pass to the SessionFactory) with a TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy

The latter is preferred since it hidse the DataSourceUtils.getConnection inside the proxy datasource.

This is of course the XML path, it should be easy to convert this to annotation based.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, the operations on Hibernate engine **does not result** in immediate SQL execution. You can trigger it manually calling `flush` on Hibernate session. Then the changes made in hibernate will be visible to the SQL code within the same transaction. As long as you do `DataSourceUtils.getConnection` to get SQL connection, because only then you'll have them run in **the same transaction**...

In the opposite direction, this is more tricky, because you have 1nd level cache (session cache), and possibly also 2nd level cache. With 2nd level cache all changes made to database will be invisible to the Hibernate, if the row is cached, until the cache expires.