# Using JPA and JDBC together

Tags: jpa, jdbc, transactions

In my project, we are upgrading an old J2EE application to Java EE 6. 
Since the business logic is quite complex, we want to retain the EJB + DAO code as much as possible. The old code uses plain JDBC for database persistence.

But in our new/upgraded application, we plan to use JPA. 
We would like to use JPA for all the read operations on database and use JDBC for the writes (inserts/updates/deletes). Is this possible in the same transaction?

For example:

- obtain an Entity Manager reference and read an employee record from the database (employee entity) using entity manager find (or a named query)
- convert the entity instance to a POJO
- update the POJO
- perform some business logic on the POJO (reuse old code as-is)
- create a JDBC connection and use a prepared statement to update the employee record in database (reuse old code as-is)

Questions:

1. If I open 2 separate connections to the database - one from JPA and another from JDBC, will it still be in the same transaction (since app server manages the JTA transaction)?
2. What are the potential issues with this approach?
3. Since I am updating the database via JDBC, the entity in persistence context will not be in sync with the database. How to handle caching in such cases?

I looked at the following related threads, but I would like to know more in detail.

- [Combining JPA and JDBC actions in one transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501230/combining-jpa-and-jdbc-actions-in-one-transaction)
- [Hibernate and JDBC in one transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153199/hibernate-and-jdbc-in-one-transaction)

Comment: JPA is built on top of JDBC; you always use them together.  You can't help it.

Comment: Some JPA providers even provide access to the Connection used by JPA, so you can add your ops and then hand it back to JPA. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jpa/datastore_connection.html